# Binary Size On chip

Tags: memory, binary, size, flash-memory

I have my code compiled for certain ARM processor and have the binary. Now I want to know the exact size in bytes (address range) it occupies on my FLASh memory.

Coz, I have certain recovery mechanism at the last 1kB of flash and don't want that to be overwritten as it needs to be there permanently.

readelf of binary gives me the start addresses ( mapped to the code & data segments) & I couldn't really map this to what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-initialize flash memory with value'ab', load binary. Read flash memory until you encounter more than 2 'ab'  values. This should give the address range in flash memory occupied by binary. ( THis is with the assumption that your binary might not have more than 2 'ab' as part of the binary)

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler/linker is based on gnu toolchain (gcc/ld)

**1/ At Compile Time**

In your linker script adjust the section size to substract 1K.
You compiler throw error if your code not fit into your flash area.

Example :

```
MEMORY
{
FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x08001000, LENGTH = 128K-1K
RAM (xrw)       : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 16K
}
```

**2/ At Run Time**

You can set a symbol in your linker script to determine the end of your program (text segment). You can use this symbol to make a runtime test

Example :

```
.text :
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
} >FLASH
```

**3/ Manually**

After compiling, use objcopy to convert your elf file to get the binary image that go into your flash. Check your datasheet to get your flash size and manually check if the file size fit into you flash minus 1K.

Exemple :

```
objcopy -O binary myfile.elf myfile.bin
```